# MySql Procedure is updating wrong condition

Tags: mysql

MySQL Procedure is updating all the 3 records and failing to execute the condition.

I have table with three records having branch id = 1,2,3 and same `UID` for the three records. and I am updating based on branch id but my query is updating all 3 records.????
Any help plzzz.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_scheduler_minmax`(
    IN minVolt DOUBLE,
    IN min_volt_time timestamp,
    IN branch int)
BEGIN
    UPDATE min_max SET 
        MIN_VOLT = minVolt,
        MIN_VOLT_TIME = min_volt_time        
        WHERE BRANCH = branch AND DEVICE_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXUID';
END
```

Comment: change the parameter names to be different from the column names. For example p_min_volt, p_min_volt_time, p_branch.

Comment: branch is creating problem if i change the name also

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_scheduler_minmax`(
    IN `_minVolt` DOUBLE,
    IN `_min_volt_time` timestamp,
    IN `_branch` int)
BEGIN
    UPDATE `min_max`
    SET `MIN_VOLT` = `_minVolt`, `MIN_VOLT_TIME` = `_min_volt_time`       
    WHERE `BRANCH` = `_branch` AND `DEVICE_ID` = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXUID';
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```